# Is it possible to allow partial payments using the PayPal Invoicing SDK?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Is it possible to allow partial payments using the PayPal Invoicing SDK?

I have tried setting the allowPartialPayments attribute to true on the InvoiceType object(see below) although once the invoice has been received there is no option to change the amount being paid.

```
InvoiceItemListType itemList = new InvoiceItemListType(invoiceItemList);

InvoiceType invoice = new InvoiceType(_MerchantEmailAddress, payerEmailAddress, itemList, "GBP");
invoice.number = brightStartInvoiceId.ToString();
invoice.merchantMemo = brightStartChildId.ToString();
invoice.allowPartialPayments = true;

CreateAndSendInvoiceRequest requestCreateAndSendInvoice = new CreateAndSendInvoiceRequest(envelopeRequest, invoice);
```